# Динамическая страница с данными Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel, openserver

Всем привет!
Как сделать динамическую страницу в laravel?

Необходимо, получить id из таблицы БД categories при наведении мыши на элемент страницы, затем происходит появление другого элемента страницы содержимое которое заполняется из таблицы subCategories предварительно фильтруясь по id из таблицы categories where('categoryId', $id).

> Говоря простым языком: Есть каталог содержащий в себе названия
> категорий. При наведении мыши  на категорию рядом появляется ещё один
> элемент в котором содержатся подкатегории. При этом для подкатегорий
> выделен всего 1 элемент т.е. он не должен дублироваться, а только
> обновлять свою содержимое.
>
> Гуглил, на русском - ничего не нашел. На английском есть решения, но я
> ничего не понял. Попил пива с чат-ботами и они мне нашептали, что
> нужно использовать AJAX запросы, но зачем (может я чего-то не понимаю
> и не знаю), если у меня все действия происходят в рамках 1 страницы.

P.s. В проекте используется ванильный JS без JQuery.

Comment: Как я понимаю, при наведении мыши, надо отправлять запрос на сервер для получения списка подкатегорий и этот список рендерить.(отображать)

Comment: Либо изначально строить структуру категорий-подкатегорий и возвращать ее клиенту, а при наведении мыши просто отображать...

Comment: @SwaD Скорее первый вариант. Но это должно быть в рамках 1 страницы